# Using an exported Object variable inside a promise

Tags: javascript, web, async-await, promise, node-modules

I have two javascript files that I am working on. On one of the files (file1.js), I have at the bottom a line for exporting an object-key variable.

```
module.exports = {randomData};
```

On the other file (file2.js), I have it included as such at the top:

```
const {randomData} = require('./file1.js');
```

Now, when I try to use this `{randomData}` object in one of my Promise parts in file2.js, it remains undefined as value. I realize that this is because the Promise code is running before the exporting part of file1.js has even finished executing to actually provide `{randomData}` with any values. I am trying to wrap things with Promises/asyncs/awaits but I'm not getting anywhere. I tried the below, thinking that it would work.

```
    var randomData = {};

function printRandomData(){
  setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(randomData);
    }, 1000);
}

function fetchRandomData(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            randomData = require('./file1.js');

            if(randomData){
                resolve();
            }
            else{
                reject('Error: Something went wrong!')
            }
        }, 2000);
    })
}

async function init() {

  await fetchRandomData(); // wait until the promise resolves (*)

  printRandomData(); // "done!"
}

init();
```

I'm expecting the above code to run `printRandomData()` last, to then output the value of `randomData`, which at that point should have been set to a different value from the `fetchRandomData()` method. However, this is not the case as the print results in an empty object. Printing from file1.js will show that `randomData` contains values however.

How do I make the `require` part happen first before anything else happens in file2.js?

Comment: Works for me. If I copy and paste that into files (providing something for `randomData` in `file1.js`) and then run it via Node.js, I see the random data I export in `file1.js` appear when printed.

Comment: Just as a side note, given your original `const {randomData} = require("./file1.js");`, you probably wanted `({randomData} = require("./file1.js"));` in your version using the promise. Second side note: You're waiting for the promise to be *settled*, not *resolved*; those aren't the same thing, a promise can be resolved but still be pending, more in [my blog post here](https://thenewtoys.dev/blog/2021/02/08/lets-talk-about-how-to-talk-about-promises/).

Comment: Could you please include the entire *file1.js* contents in your question? What is `randomdData` initialised with before you're exporting it?

Comment: Why are you using `setTimeout` in *file2.js*? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You need a better strategy: 
(1) If the data needs to be cached, then cache it in  'file1.js'.
(2) Instead of exporting the data from 'file1.js', export a `getRandomData()` function.
(3) Instead of keeping a local reference to the data in 'file2.js', call `getRandomData()` wherever the data is needed.
Exactly what you write in  'file1.js' will depend on whether the data is synchronously of asynchronously derived.